# edit UPS HAT safe shutdown script

Tags: shutdown, hat, ups

I write this since I need advice with an RPi Hat that I purchased and the assistance told me to find a solution myself!

I purchased an UPS HAT ([UPS3](https://raspberrypiwiki.com/UPS3#User_Manual) from geekworm).
I need to perform some actions before shutdown, therefore the off switch button, instead of just a safe shutdown, should send a command to the RPi.

From your knowledge, can this button's "script" to RPi be edited in order to perform this action before the actual safe shutdown?

Let's say:

1. switch off pressed
2. message sent from UPS HAT to RPi in order to manage an additional/external operation from the RPi (in my case is safely shutdown a device from a RPi's Gpio)
3. RPi safe shutdown

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by placing the command you want to execute before `sudo halt -h` in [smartups.py](https://github.com/geekworm-com/ups3/blob/master/smartups.py):

```
...
if ((bq25895_status['Input'] != 'Connected') and (max17048_soc < POWEROFF_POWER)):
                count = count + 1
                #print bq25895_status['Input']
                if count > 10:
                    logging.warning("Shutdown")
                    os.system("YOUR COMMAND")
                    os.system("sudo halt -h")
...
```

Then restart the smartups service to apply the change.

Comment: hi Sergiusz.
I tried adding :
- logging.warning("Shutdown")
- os.system("sudo python3 myscript.py")
- time.sleep(10)
- os.system("sudo halt -h")

but when i push the on/off button, the RPi shuts down directly without running the script or even waiting the 10 seconds as for time.sleep(10)
am i doing it wrong?
i believe could be that i didn't restart the smartups service but no idea how to do it

Comment: Try ```sudo service --status-all```
If it lists smartups, then use ```sudo service smartups restart```

Comment: unfortunately still no luck. i am modifying the smartups.py in this path "/home/pi/ups3" the script that i want to run (in the smartups.py script I added the string: "os.system(sudo python3 myscript.py)" is within the same folder in the terminal,

**cd ups3**,
**sudo service smartups restart**,
**sudo reboot**.


but at the new boot up, nor **myscript.py**, nor **time.sleep(10)** are not executed when i press the off button

Comment: 1. Try placing your script in ```/usr/local/bin/```  
2. Add ```logging.warning("TEST")```, save, restart service and perform shutdown.  
3. Check ```/var/log/smartups.log``` to see if *TEST* has been logged.

Comment: After trying that, I don't see anything in the Log session. I don't even see **''Shutdown"** which I'm supposed to see if I'm not wrong.   
Also, **sudo service --status all** does not list smartups so I believe the issue lies here.
Unfortunately, I'm still new to this world..
 When i try to run the installer with **sudo ./install.sh**, i get the **ERROR: XMLRPC request failed [code: -32500] RuntimeError: Pypi's XMLRPC Api is currently disabled due to unmeneageable load and will be deprecated in the near future**. (therefore I installed the XMLRPC package manually but without result)